# How to perceive in code if developer pressed F5 or Ctrl-F5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

How can I perceive in code (C#) if developer pressed F5 or Ctrl-F5 prior to execute solution in VS2010?

if (F5Pressed)
{do something}
else
{do some other thing}

Comment: Are you developing a plugin or just wanting to do conditional code if the debugger is attached?

Comment: Only add code if debugger is attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
       Console.WriteLine("f5");
     else
       Console.WriteLine("ctrl f5");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();

}
```

---

This works in the general case, but is not exactly what you asked for.  As other debuggers could be attached, also if you just run the exe by double clicking it will report that crtl f5 was pressed.